# How to fix SIGBUS on Solaris

Tags: c++, memory, solaris

I am using `atomic_inc_64_nv` on 64bit Solaris, returned value is casted to unsigned long.
But when I run my app, it crashed and core is claming that the cause of the crash is SIGBUS. I Suspect there are could be alignment issues. How can I fix this problem?

Here is my function which uses increment

```
    inline unsigned long long Increment64(volatile unsigned long long * pullTarget)
    {
#if defined(LINUX)
        return Add64(pullTarget, 1ULL);
#elif defined(SOLARIS)
        return atomic_inc_64_nv((volatile unsigned long *)pullTarget) - 1ULL;
#elif defined(WIN32)
        return (unsigned long long)InterlockedIncrement64((LONGLONG volatile*)(pullTarget)) - 1ULL;
#endif // defined(LINUX)
    }
```

Thank you on advance.

Comment: Did you try a debugger? Without code it will be hard to help you.  Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Please take a look at the function posted above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sparc processors do not support unaligned access. You need to make sure your `pullTarget` is aligned to 8 bytes. You can add some code like this to catch it:

if ((uint_ptr)pullTarget & 7)
   {
      printf("Alignment problem pullTarget = %p\n", pullTarget);
   }

Answer (score 2):

As you have a core and have opened it in the debugger, now simply print the value contained in the variable `pullTarget`.  (The pointer value itself, not what it points to.)  You should see that it is not divisible by 8, as @MatsPetersson is correct on the cause.

Comment: And most likely the bug will be in whatever called this function.